# C code for tone generator in linux

Tags: c, ubuntu, alsa

I want to write a c code to generate tone using array output to DAC in ubuntu. (preferably alsa driver)

For example:
I need to be able to send voltage output to DAC like 1100000 etc. to be able to generate a tone. Is it possible?

P.S. I had a look at [tones](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/tones.1.html). Is it possible to do that using a c code rather than a bash command?

Comment: Why not get the source of the utility & take it from there? You can get the source of the package which has `tones` and have a look at how it works

Comment: Yeah you are right, but that would be too complicated. I think I could do with a simpler code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [pcspkr_pcm.c](http://dev.medozas.de/gitweb.cgi?p=hxtools;a=blob;f=smm/pcspkr_pcm.c;hb=HEAD) as a starting point perhaps. It is used by (bsvplay, qplay) also from within the hxtools suite.